Deep RL problem: Loss decreases but agent doesn't learn
I'm implementing a basic Vanilla Policy Gradient algorithm for the CartPole-v1 gymnasium environment, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. No matter what I try, during the training loop the loss decreases (so the model is actually learning something), but the episode total reward also decreases until it reaches around 9-10 steps (which I imagine is the minimum number of steps needed to make the pole fall). So it's learning to do it bad!
In this algorithm there are a few moving parts that influence each other, and I run out of ideas to see where the problem could be.
For the discounted rewards I'm using
$ Q_{k,t} = \sum_{i=0}{\gamma^{i-t} r_i} $
for $k$ = all episodes and $t$ = all steps in an episode.
And for the loss:
$ L = -\sum_{k,t}Q_{k,t}log\pi_{\theta}(a_t | s_t)$
The code is a mix from Maxim Lapan's Deep RL Hands-On book, Karpathy's Pong example (blog, code), and personal tweaks.
Here's my code:
import gymnasium as gym
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.nn.init import xavier_uniform_
import numpy as np

GAMMA = 0.99
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
BATCH_SIZE = 4
DEVICE = torch.device('mps')


class XavierLinear(nn.Linear):
    def __init__(self, in_features: int, out_features: int, bias: bool = True, device=None, dtype=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(in_features, out_features, bias, device, dtype)
        xavier_uniform_(self.weight)


class VPG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(VPG, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            XavierLinear(input_size, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            XavierLinear(128, output_size), 
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return F.softmax(self.net(x), dim=0)


def run_episode(model, env):
    obs = env.reset()[0]
    obs = torch.Tensor(env.reset()[0]).to(DEVICE)
    te = tr = False
    rewards, outputs, actions = [], [], []
    while not (te or tr):
        probs = model(obs)
        action = probs.multinomial(1).item()
        obs, r, te, tr, _ = env.step(action)
        obs = torch.Tensor(obs).to(DEVICE)
        if (te or tr):
            r = 0 # Here I also tried -1 if the pole falls and 0 otherwise
        rewards.append(r)
        outputs.append(probs)
        actions.append(action)
    return torch.Tensor(rewards).to(DEVICE), torch.concatenate(outputs).reshape(len(rewards), 2), actions

def discount_rewards(rewards):
    discounted_r = torch.zeros_like(rewards)
    additive_r = 0
    for idx in range(len(rewards)-1, -1, -1):
        to_add = GAMMA * additive_r
        additive_r = to_add + rewards[idx]
        discounted_r[idx] = additive_r
    return discounted_r.to(DEVICE)

def loss_function(discounted_r, probs, actions):
    logprobs = torch.log(probs)
    selected = logprobs[range(probs.shape[0]), actions]
    # discounted_r = (discounted_r - discounted_r.mean()) / discounted_r.std()
    weighted = selected * discounted_r
    return -weighted.sum()

# The actual training loop:

episode_total_reward = 0
batch_losses = torch.Tensor().to(DEVICE)
batch_actions = []
batch_disc_r = torch.Tensor().to(DEVICE)
batch_probs = torch.Tensor().to(DEVICE)
best_ep_reward = 0
losses, ep_total_lenghts = [], [0]

episodes = 0
TARGET_REWARD = 100

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
model = VPG(env.observation_space.shape[0],
            2).to(DEVICE)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)

while np.array(ep_total_lenghts)[-100:].mean() < TARGET_REWARD:
    rewards, probs, actions = run_episode(model, env)
    discounted_r = discount_rewards(rewards)
    episode_total_reward = rewards.shape[0]
    ep_total_lenghts.append(episode_total_reward)
    episodes += 1
    batch_actions += actions
    batch_disc_r = torch.concatenate([batch_disc_r, discounted_r])    
    batch_probs = torch.concatenate([batch_probs, probs])    

    if episodes % BATCH_SIZE == 0:
        loss = loss_function(batch_disc_r, batch_probs, batch_actions)
        losses.append(loss.item())
        model.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optim.step()
        batch_actions = []
        batch_disc_r = torch.Tensor().to(DEVICE)
        batch_probs = torch.Tensor().to(DEVICE)
        print(f"Episode {episodes}. Loss: {loss}. Reward: {episode_total_reward}")
print(f"Success in {episodes} episodes. Loss: {loss}. Reward: {episode_total_reward}")

Tried: changing signs in loss functions, changing rewards (non-terminal step = 0 and terminal step = -1), updating manually the weights (adding the gradient or substracting it instead of using Adam optimizer). In each case I get the same: the loss decreases but the agent doens't learn to keep the pole up. Actually, it learns to throw it.
Expectation: Loss decreases and episode total reward (steps played) increases.

I'm pretty sure you should throw a minus sign in front of the selected log probability in your loss function. (this turned out to be wrong and the code works fine: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ecnqb_D_Oe0_kMc2ZnA6stAlVCbAyE9H?usp=sharin)

Doesn't the minus sign in front of weighted.sum() a couple of lines below have the same effect?
I tried that and the output was the same. The loss was decreasing during training, but the agent was perfoming worse every time. It really puzzles me

yeah you're right.
ive tried to run your code just now and I dont get the same result

I have a link to a colab where I ran the code it worked and I turned a copy of it into A2C.
link
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ecnqb_D_Oe0_kMc2ZnA6stAlVCbAyE9H?usp=sharin

Wow, thanks for taking the time Leonhard!
Yeah, this morning I did those changes, and I also changed the reward for -1 if the episode is terminated, and 0 otherwise, and worked perfectly.
I still don't know exactly what was happening before. I was really confused by having a decreasing loss and the agent performing worse and worse each time.
But anyway, it works now.
And thanks for the A2C implementation! I'm studying RL at the moment and that will help me!

No worries show me the next step you take please
